# Loading ontology to extract all the imported name spaces

Tags: java, protege, owl-api

I am trying to load an ontology saved on my PC. The file format is .n3. 
After a lot of work and searching for the possible solutions, I didn't find an appropriate way to load an ontology.

I tried the following code:

```
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL;
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.OWLModel;

public class Extractor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ontologyURI = "file:///C:/acco.n3";
    try {

        OWLModel owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(ontologyURI);       
        System.out.println("Worked");

    }catch (Exception exception) {  
        System.out.println("Error can't upload the ontologie ");
    }
}
}
```

but it always gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node.<clinit>(Node.java:35)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl.fresh(ResourceImpl.java:108)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl.<init>(ResourceImpl.java:68)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory$Impl.createResource(ResourceFactory.java:176)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory.createResource(ResourceFactory.java:69)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF.resource(RDF.java:29)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF.<clinit>(RDF.java:37)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.impl.XMLLiteralType.<clinit>(XMLLiteralType.java:30)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.TypeMapper.<clinit>(TypeMapper.java:52)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.OWLSystemFrames.createRDFSDatatypes(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.OWLSystemFrames.createOWLInstances(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.OWLSystemFrames.createOWLMetaModel(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.OWLSystemFrames.<init>(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.swrl.SWRLSystemFrames.<init>(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.AbstractOWLModel.createSystemFrames(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.AbstractOWLModel.createSystemFrames(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.DefaultKnowledgeBase.<init>(DefaultKnowledgeBase.java:79)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.AbstractOWLModel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaOWLModel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaKnowledgeBaseFactory.createKnowledgeBase(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createDomainKB(Project.java:429)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createDomainKnowledgeBase(Project.java:447)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.creator.OwlProjectFromUriCreator.create(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(Unknown Source)
at Extractor.main(Extractor.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 25 more
```

I need your help in solving this error, or perhaps find a way to load ontologies to extract knowledge from them.
Thanks in advance.

---

Update:

I added the missing dependencies to the class path as @Roddy of the Frozen Peas suggested.

but it gives me the following error:

```
WARNING: [Local Folder Repository] The specified file must be a directory. (C:\eclipse-workspace\NewEx\plugins\edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl) -- LocalFolderRepository.update()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/protege/editor/owl/model/hierarchy/roots/Relation
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.parser.TripleProcessor.<init>(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.parser.GlobalParserCache.getTripleProcessor(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.parser.ProtegeOWLParser.loadTriples(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.parser.ProtegeOWLParser.run(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaKnowledgeBaseFactory.loadKnowledgeBase(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.loadDomainKB(Project.java:1346)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createDomainKnowledgeBase(Project.java:456)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.creator.OwlProjectFromUriCreator.create(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(Unknown Source)
at Extractor.main(Extractor.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.protege.editor.owl.model.hierarchy.roots.Relation
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 10 more
```

any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you try adding that dependency to your classpath? It's just a logging library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.protege.editor.owl.model.hierarchy.roots.Relation`

There are other dependencies you need. Rather than going piecemeal, you should use a build system that can resolve the dependency closure for you, such as Maven, Gradle or similar.

The problem here is not Protege specific or ontology related, it's just plain Java libraries missing from the classpath.

Note that your code does not use OWL API. These classes are Jena classes and Protege classes (from Protege 3.x, I'd think). Note that Protege 3.x is a very dated API. Consider using a newer version (5.2.0 or newer), or directly using the actual OWL API. See https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation

OWL API also has zip files containing all dependencies, which might simplify your work (Maven is still better than resolving dependencies by hand). See https://github.com/owlcs/releases/tree/master/owlapi/5

Comment: You are right, Thank you for this answer. First I used the OWL API, but it throws some exceptions while parsing some vocabularies (I need to parse more than 600 vocabs and extract the namespaces from them). So I changed my code and used Jena libraries. I will try to rebuild my code and use the OWL API. I found better in extracting the information I need.